# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'layers')

Tags: node.js, undefined

After all the work is done, I try to run my code (node index.js) and this error appears:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\mi pc.DESKTOP-1K26KAH\Desktop\generative-art-opensource-3> node index.js
> C:\Users\mi pc.DESKTOP-1K26KAH\Desktop\generative-art-opensource-3\index.js:119
>  _races[_race].layers.forEach((layer) => {
>                ^
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'layers')
> at createDna (C:\Users\mi pc.DESKTOP-1K26KAH\Desktop\generative-art-opensource-3\index.js:119:17)
> at startCreating (C:\Users\mi pc.DESKTOP-1K26KAH\Desktop\generative-art-opensource-3\index.js:148:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mi pc.DESKTOP-1K26KAH\Desktop\generative-art-opensource-3\index.js:180:1)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
> ```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the code inside index.js.

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell from this information is that your dictionary object `_races` does not have any value for the current key `_race`.  Therefore `_races[_race]` is `undefined` and `_races[_race].layers` is a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'layers')

You can suppress possible errors with the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.`

```
_races[_race]?.layers.forEach((layer) => {
```

Or by checking `if (_races[_race]) {` to rule out `undefined` before trying to access `.layers`.

But you'll probably want to figure out *why* `_races[_race]` is `undefined`.